# Javascript Validation form onsubmit not returning false

Tags: javascript, html

Note : i searched similar questions and still couldn't fix it so i'm asking again.
i have a form and its `onsubmit = "return submit()"`. it checks if textarea is empty. If it is then it returns false but that doesn't work.The action still goes to the next website even if text area is empty.

```
        let firstName = document.querySelector('#firstname');
    let lastName = document.querySelector('#lastname');
    let password = document.querySelector('#password');
    let retypePass = document.querySelector('#repassword');
    let radioMale = document.querySelector('#male');
    let radioFemale = document.querySelector('#female');
    let textArea = document.querySelector('#textarea');
    let select= document.querySelector('#select');
    let button = document.querySelector('#button');
    let form = document.querySelector('#form');

    function submit(){
        if (textArea.value = "") {
           textArea.nextElementSibling.innerHTML = "Fill this box";
           return false;
     }
  }
HTML :`


    <div class='wrapper'>
    <h1>Registration Form</h1>
    <form  action="http://google.com" id='form' onsubmit="return submit()">
        <input placeholder="First Name" type="text" id='firstname' required>
        <span></span>
        <br>
        <input placeholder="Last Name" type="text" id='lastname' required>
        <span></span>
        <br>
        <input placeholder="Password" type="text" id='password' required>
        <span></span>
        <br>
        <input placeholder="Retype Password" type="text" id='repassword' required>
        <span></span>
        <br>
        <input placeholder="Phone Number" type="tel" id='tel' >
        <br>
        <div class='radio'>
            <h4>Selector Your Gender</h4>
            <input type='radio'name='same' id='male'>Male
            <input type='radio'name='same' id='female'>Female
        </div>
        <p style="margin:5px 0px;color:white">ADDRESS:</p>
        <textarea id='textarea'></textarea>
        <span></span>

        <p style="margin:5px 0px;color:white">Country:</p>
        <select type='country' style="width:84%" id='select'>
            <option>England</option>
            <option>Japan</option>
            <option>America</option>
            <option>France</option>
            <option>NetherLands</option>
        </select>
        <br><br>
        <input type='submit' value='submit'>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you considered just using `<textarea required>`?

Comment: i need to learn to implement validation etc manually for future use when i create complex forms.

Comment: @AfaqQazi whilst i cherish the idea of learning and all, form validation is a serious topic and you cannot learn it upfront like this. Just think of input fields for telephone numbers and how much checking you'd need to do there... a simply "textarea is empty" doesn't really make you learn much in comparison at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must change the name of the function

Example

```
<form action="http://google.com" id='form' onsubmit="return validate()">
```

and

```
function validate() {
    if (textArea.value == "") {
        textArea.nextElementSibling.innerHTML = "Fill this box";
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! it worked could you explain please why i can't write other names ?

Comment: You can't use "submit()" because the form already use to send the request.. I think so, but I'm not sure

Answer (score 1):

Your if systax was wrong:

```
if (textArea.value = "")
```

It should be:

```
if (textArea.value == "")
```

Comment: Hello! Just to let you know, questions where the answer consists of a simple typo should be voted-to-close. You don't have your close-hammer yet, but these questions don't add value to the site.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol but is this the case of a simple typo though? What if the poster doesnt understand the difference of `=` and `==` and didn't make a typo but instead wrote what he thought was right? It is not a close the question case, since the OP would then still be lost as to how to fix it, no?

Comment: Hello thanks i fixed it but it still moves on to next website :(

Comment: I hoped that ^^. But when I look the form element:
<form  action="http://google.com" id='form' onsubmit="return submit()">
and the get textArea:
let textArea = document.querySelector('#textarea');
All of them very simple, I think just because syntax.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
if (!textArea.value) {
       textArea.nextElementSibling.innerHTML = "Fill this box";
       return false;
 }
```

**OR**

```
if (textArea.value == '') {
       textArea.nextElementSibling.innerHTML = "Fill this box";
       return false;
 }
```